# How to reset cursor position to start of inputText?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I wanted to reset cursor position if text in textinput is longer but i am not sure how to achieve this. Here is my code.

```
constructor(){
  this.state = {  
     selection:{start:0,end:0}
  }

}

.....

resetCursor = () => {
    const selection = {start:1,end:1};
    this.subject.setNativeProps({selection});
    this.setState({selection});
}

.....

<Input
  ref = {ref => this.subject = ref}
  placeholder="Subject"
  selection={this.state.selection} 
  inputContainerStyle={Styles.inputContainer}
  inputStyle={Styles.inputBlackStyle}
  placeholderTextColor={"#d3d3d3"}
  onChangeText={subject => {
  this.setState({ subject });}}
  onBlur = {this.resetCursor}
/>
```

What I am doing wrong in here !!